# What happens when search bar is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

[image: on image you can see how search bar appears on top of main view when its pressed, but i need it on top of menu]

I'm making an iPhone app with sideswipe menu. Menu contains search bar. The problem is when search bar is pressed main view (UIView with some images) covers tableView and search bar appears on top of view, but I want press on search bar and move that main view from the screen and make tableView and search bar the same size as screen and this transition from smaller size to size of screen, for both search bar and table view, have to appear at same time.

I tried to change frames in searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch and searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch methods but search bar changes his size in its own manner and it appears to fast.

Is there any way how I can get control of it or what happens when search bar is pressed? Is there any method I can't see but have to overwrite?

Comment: a screenshot would be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: If you use searchDisplayController what you say is the default effect. If not probably it's how you implement your sideswipe menu that cause this problem